# Mixing lines using query on MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb, mixing

I am trying to do a query to join two tables.

```
select distinct 
  ext.COD_FRENTE_CHEG, ext.COD_DIVI2_SAIDA,
  vaz.ABV_DIVI2_LOG,ext.DATA_SAIDA,
  ext.CIE_PESO_LIQUIDO, ext.CIE_HR_CHEG_CAMPO, ext.CIE_HR_SAI_CAMPO,
  ext.CIE_DATA_CHEG, ext.COD_MIS_MOTRIZ_SAIDA,ext.CIE_USER,
  ext.CIE_FORCADO, ext.CIE_OBSERV,  ext.CIC_DIST_MED
from ga_ciclos_externos ext 
 left outer join ga_lgt_vazao vaz
 on (ext.cod_divi2_cheg = vaz.COD_DIVI2_LOG 
 and ext.COD_FRENTE_CHEG = vaz.COD_FRENTE_LOG) 
where ext.SAF_ANO_SAFRA_CHEG = '2016' and ext.cod_empr_cheg = '2' 
order by ext.data_saida
```

I am having a problem because some lines are mixing with the column `cod_divi2_log`.

I am using MariaDB.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to indent your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in to provide additional detail that's necessary to identify the specific problem, and more importantly a *specific question*. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the support. 
The problem is not on the query, I had a problem directly from database.